# How can I extend the functionality of this script?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

The following script allows a user to either fill out the textboxes in a gridview control with a checkbox called **grid1Details**.

If the user chooses not to fill out the textboxes, then the user must check the **grid1Details** checkbox in other to submit the form.

If the user does not put a checkmark on the checkbox or does not enter values into all three textboxes, then the user gets our custom alert message ***"Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox."***

This works great and here is that script:

```
      <script type="text/javascript">
          function validate() {
              var checkbox = document.getElementById("<%=grid1Details.ClientID %>");
              var txtsourcename = $("[id*='txtsourcename']")[0];
              var txtsourceaddress = $("[id*='txtsourceaddress']")[0];
              var txtsourceincome = $("[id*='txtsourceincome']")[0];

              if (checkbox.checked) {
                  if ($(txtsourcename).val().length != 0 && $(txtsourceaddress).val().length != 0 && $(txtsourceincome).val().length != 0) {
                      jAlert("Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox.");
                      return false;
                  } else {
                      return true;
                  }
              } else {
                  if ($(txtsourcename).val().length != 0 && $(txtsourceaddress).val().length != 0 && $(txtsourceincome).val().length != 0) {
                      return true;
                  } else {
                      jAlert("Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox.");
                      return false;
                  }
              }
           }
   </script>
```

The issue we are having now is that we have several gridview controls, each with its own checkbox control and must be validated the same way.

In the next script, we are trying to add **spouseDetails** checkbox but it is not working.

Each time, we either enter data into the two checkbox controls, the **grid1Details** control and **spouseDetails** checkbox control and hit the submit button, it doesn't validate the **spouseDetails** checkbox.

The **grid1Details** checkbox gets validated but the **spouseDetails** checkbox is ignored.

Any ideas what we are doing wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate() {
        var checkbox = document.getElementById("<%=grid1Details.ClientID %>");
        var txtsourcename = $("[id*='txtsourcename']")[0];
        var txtsourceaddress = $("[id*='txtsourceaddress']")[0];
        var txtsourceincome = $("[id*='txtsourceincome']")[0];

        //spouse check
        checkbox = document.getElementById("<%=spouseDetails.ClientID%>");
        var txtspousename = $("[id*='txtspousename']")[0];
        var txtspouseaddress = $("[id*='txtspouseaddress']")[0];
        var txtspouseincome = $("[id*='txtspouseincome']")[0];

        if (checkbox.checked) {
            if ($(txtsourcename).val().length != 0 && $(txtsourceaddress).val().length != 0 && $(txtsourceincome).val().length != 0) {
                jAlert("Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox.");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
            if ($(txtspousename).val().length != 0 && $(txtspouseaddress).val().length != 0 && $(txtspouseincome).val().length != 0) {
                jAlert("Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox.");
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }            
        } else {
            if ($(txtsourcename).val().length != 0 && $(txtsourceaddress).val().length != 0 && $(txtsourceincome).val().length != 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                jAlert("Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox.");
                return false;
            }
            if ($(txtspousename).val().length != 0 && $(txtspouseaddress).val().length != 0 && $(txtspouseincome).val().length != 0) {
                return true;
            } else {
                jAlert("Please enter values on all textboxes or check the checkbox next to each textbox.");
                return false;
            }            
        }
    }
   </script>


//click button:
      <td> <asp:Button ID="btnNext" CssClass="btnNext" runat="server" Text=" Review Form " OnClientClick="BtnClick(); return validate()" OnClick="btnNext_Click" /></td>


 <table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="grid1Details" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Grid1CheckChanged" /><span style="color:#ff0000">*</span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:gridview ID="Gridview1" gridlines="None" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowdatabound="Gridview1_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="Gridview1_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" Visible="false" HeaderText="Row Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
             <headerstyle horizontalalign="Left" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtsourcename" placeholder="Name..." runat="server" style="width:250px;" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtsourceaddress" placeholder="Address..." runat="server" style="width:250px;" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Income">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtsourceincome" placeholder="Income...(example: 1000)" runat="server" style="width:250px;" class="form-control txtsourceincome numeric"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" 
                        onclick="ButtonAdd_Click" CssClass="grvAddButton" OnClientClick="return ValidateEmptyValue();return validate()" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True"><ControlStyle CssClass="grvDelButton" /></asp:CommandField>
            </Columns>
          </asp:gridview>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="spouseDetails" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="SpouseCheckChanged" /><span style="color:#ff0000">*</span>
        </td>
        <td>                     
            <asp:gridview ID="grvspouse" GridLines="None" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" onrowdatabound="grvspouse_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="grvspouse_RowDeleting">
            <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SpouseNumber" Visible="false" HeaderText="Row Number" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <headerstyle horizontalalign="Left" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtspousename" placeholder="Name..." runat="server" style="width:250px;" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtspouseaddress" placeholder="Address..." runat="server" style="width:250px;" class="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Income">
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtspouseincome" placeholder="Income...(example: 1000)" runat="server" style="width:250px;" class="form-control txtsourceincome numeric"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd2" runat="server" Text="Add" 
                        onclick="ButtonAdd2_Click" CssClass="grvAddButton" OnClientClick="return ValidateSPEmptyValue();" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
           <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True"><ControlStyle CssClass="grvDelButton" /></asp:CommandField>
            </Columns>
          </asp:gridview>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
  <td> <asp:Button ID="btnNext" CssClass="btnNext" runat="server" Text=" Review Form " OnClientClick="BtnClick(); return validate()" OnClick="btnNext_Click" /></td>
```

Comment: Hey, just want to make a comment that it seems like you're selecting the first element via an ID. IDs should be unique and if they aren't you need to use classes

Comment: @Andrew, as you can seem they are all unique, grid1Details, spouseDetails, etc. but thanks for your suggestion. If you have a better code sample, I would appreciate seeing it.

Comment: I cant see your HTML so I don't whether they are unique. The way you are accessing them eg $("[id*='txtspouseincome']")[0]; tells me that they aren't unique. If they're unique you can select them like so $("#txtspouseincome");

Comment: We would need to see your HTML to answer the question

Comment: @Andrew, I posted a couple of gridview controls jus to show what I am working with.

Thanks for your help.